# 3 studded zig-zag brick

Tags: set-identification

I have a bag of bricks - one brick has 3 studs and it is a zigzag shape. Any ideas which set could it be?

It is cream coloured and among the other pieces included is an 8 sided dark grey flat plate.

Comment: Can you provide a photo or additional infomation?

Comment: When you say Zig-Zag, is it this kind of shape you have in mind? https://www.bricklink.com/PL/2462.jpg

Comment: A picture of the entire bag, with pieces clearly visible, will aid tremendously in determining which set the bag is from.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like it could be a [Brick, Modified Facet 3 x 3 (2462) in tan](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=2462&colorID=2&in=A).

[Hogwarts Castle (4th edition)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=4842) has that piece as well as an [8 sided dark grey flat plate](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=89523&v=2&in=A&colorID=85&srt=0&srtAsc=A&ov=Y). But without knowing what other parts you have, it could be several other sets (such as #75953 and #10235 as mentioned in the comments).

Comment: Could also be "Hogwarts Whomping Willow (75953)" set.

Comment: Or 10235 Winter Village Market. In other words: we need a good picture of the bag and its contents to accurately determine what you have.

Comment: It doesn't look like there is a lot to go on but it could be any of those sets potentially.